# MySQL - Ordering all data in alphabetical order but placing a particular item last

Tags: mysql, sql

Assuming I have the following, data from a field:

```
Category Name
-------------

Games
Movies
All
Music
Software
```

I want to order the above data in alphabetical (ascending) order but I want 'All' to appear last at the bottom of the list. Not sure how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ORDER BY category_name='All' ASC, category_name ASC`

Comment: haven't tested, but wouldn't this put 'All' at the top of the list rather than at the bottom?

Comment: @Brian Driscoll : If you want it on top, then `ORDER BY category_name='All' DESC, category_name ASC`. You might have asked about my very first version (which is already fixed, I didn't notice we wanted it at the bottom).

Comment: I'll take your word for it since I'm at work currently and don't have time to test. I'm sure it's right, just doesn't seem intuitive (to me).

Comment: Thanks the original solution: `ORDER BY category_name='All' ASC, category_name ASC` has worked for me.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: You can add `IF` or `CASE` around the first condition, i.e. `ORDER BY IF(category_name='All',1,0), category_name` or `ORDER BY CASE WHEN category_name='All' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, category_name ` if you think it's more readable, but it will work exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Category_Name, if(Category_Name='All',1,0) as orderAid
FROM CategoryTable
ODER BY orderAid, Category_Name
```

Comment: This is a very interesting answer. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need for that complexity, `catname = 'all'` evaluates to `0` if false and `1` if true.