# SQL Server: ordering all data in alphabetical order but placing a particular item last

Tags: sql, sql-server

[MySQL - Ordering all data in alphabetical order but placing a particular item last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246134/mysql-ordering-all-data-in-alphabetical-order-but-placing-a-particular-item-la)

This question is already asked for MySql, unfortunatly this solution doesn't work for SQL Server. This is my current query and result:

```
select ShipMethodID As UseMe, Name As ShowMe 
from Purchasing.ShipMethod
union
Select 0 As UseMe, 'n/a' As ShowMe
order by ShowMe
```

Results:

```
5   CARGO TRANSPORT 5
0   n/a
4   OVERNIGHT J-FAST
3   OVERSEAS - DELUXE
1   XRQ - TRUCK GROUND
2   ZY - EXPRESS
```

I need to get my sorting like this:

```
0   n/a
5   CARGO TRANSPORT 5
4   OVERNIGHT J-FAST
3   OVERSEAS - DELUXE
1   XRQ - TRUCK GROUND
2   ZY - EXPRESS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from (
    select ShipMethodID As UseMe, Name As ShowMe 
    from Purchasing.ShipMethod
    union
    Select 0 As UseMe, 'n/a' As ShowMe
) t
order by (case when UseMe = 0 then null else ShowMe end)
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'UseMe'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'ShowMe'.
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: @Jeroen - are you sure you're running the whole statement? It should run fine with union as well

Comment: You can't order by ShowMe, you need to order by (case when UseMe = 0 then null else 'n/a' end)

Comment: Ah you can't use a column alias in an expression in an `order by`. Column aliases are only valid on their own. [An amended version that works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/25db3/1)

Comment: This is weird actually. It can't order by aliases that are in a case! See updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Order first by a field simply to get the N/A first, then by the field you really want to sort by - if you actually want n/a last then `order by DisplayOrder DESC, ShowMe`.

```
select      ShipMethodID As UseMe, Name As ShowMe, 1 AS DisplayOrder
from        Purchasing.ShipMethod
union
Select      0 As UseMe, 'n/a' As ShowMe, 0 AS DisplayOrder
order by    DisplayOrder, ShowMe
```

Answer (score 2):

Please tried with this query..

```
select ShipMethodID As UseMe, Name As ShowMe, 1 As dummycolumn
from Purchasing.ShipMethod
union
Select 0 As UseMe, 'n/a' As ShowMe, 0 As dummycolumn
order by dummycolumn, ShowMe
```